# Can someone explain what is a mining RPC?

Tags: bitcoind

I just read about [this update](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/3368).

What does a mining `RPC` mean and stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RPC stands for [Remote Procedure Call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) and it is a technology that allows you to perform actions on a machine being on another machine (or on the same machine but in a different process).

The new RPC calls from the update are calls related to Bitcoin mining. Most mining software will use these calls to get information from the bitcoind client running on the same machine.

So, nothing to do with crypto, just an extension of the API you don't have to worry about.